# How to hide tile on Android Maps v2

Tags: android-maps-v2, tile

Is there a way to hide map (make not visible) tiles in Google Maps v2?

I want have all other functions of Maps (markers, info window) but instead of map I want to have static background image. As turnaround I tried use tile overlay but it is loading multiple images, not one, and there still is loaded first original map tile.

Is there an option to do that with Google Maps v2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set a static image (Tile overlay is for creating lots of tiles and you should do a lot of calculation to recreate the correct background you want) and ground overlay wants a position (you could think at creating one ground overlay at the center of the map visible and set height and width to be the visible area of the map (there should be a method on GoogleMap object to obtain visible area).

About disabling tiles, you can set

GoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMapType(int)